# React to Event Handler Creation

Tags: c#

I want to use the C# `EventHandler`, but only really throw the events if necessary. Let's see this example code:

```
    class EventHandlerExample {
        const int Max = 10;

        static void Main() {
            var counter = new EventHandlerExample();
            counter.OnFinished += (_, args) => Console.WriteLine($"More than threshold: {args.Threshold}");
            
            Console.WriteLine("Starting the count...");
            for (int i = 0; i < Max; i++) {
                Console.WriteLine($" - incrementing to {i + 1}");
                counter.Increment();
            }
        }

        private readonly int _threshold = new Random().Next(Max);
        private int _total;

        private void Increment() {
            _total++;
            if (_total >= _threshold) {
                var args = new FinishedEventArgs {
                    Threshold = _threshold,
                };
                OnFinished?.Invoke(this, args);
            }
        }

        public event EventHandler<FinishedEventArgs> OnFinished;
    }
    
    public class FinishedEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public int Threshold { get; init; }
    }
```

The `OnFinished EventHandler` gets initialized when the first event listener gets added, so in the above example it's always not-null, if you remove the `counter.OnFinished += ...` line it's always null. And even if you do this...

```
    EventHandler<FinishedEventArgs> onFinished = (_, args) => Console.WriteLine($"More than threshold: {args.Threshold}");
    counter.OnFinished += onFinished;
    counter.OnFinished -= onFinished;
```

...then `OnFinished` will return to being null, which is a great start. Now in my case, the setup to fire the event (which is the `Increment()` method in the example) is very high-cost. And since I need to patch another method with Harmony, I can't just do it in the `Increment()` method on-the-fly after checking if `OnFinished` is not null. On the flipside, I want to remove this high-cost code when all listeners have unregistered again, which is a use case for me.

So what I need is an event for the creation and destruction of the `EventHandler`. Something like:

```
    OnFinished.OnCreate += SetupHighCostCode;
    OnFinished.OnDestruction += TearDownHighCostCode;
```

Is anything like that possible? Or how else can I achieve something like this? Right now I'm just managing my event listener list myself and react to `Add()` and `Remove()`.

Comment: *"Right now I'm just managing my event listener list myself and react to Add() and Remove()"*. That's how you would do it. Check out [this blog post](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/11/defining-and-raising-custom-events.html) of mine and see whether there's anything new there but it sounds like you may already know all you need to. The most relevant stuff is towards the end so you may want to skim it first.

Comment: Did I understand correctly you want to call OnCreate when the first listenser is registered and call OnDestruction when the last listenser is unregistered?

Comment: @shingo Yes, only during the lifecycle of my application, I expect both to be called multiple times. So (1) listeners are registered and setup is called (2) listeners listen (3) listeners are unregistered and tear down is called (4) time flies (5) listeners are registered and setup is called (6) listeners listen...

Comment: You current method is almost the only choice, wrapping the event with a struct could be another one. This is because 1. you cannot extend from Delegate type, 2. you cannot track the event object.